# Google location is inaccurate without GPS

Tags: google-location-history

Using a Samsung Galaxy 4S. I'm using Google location history. I pulled location history and broke it down by the minute. GPS was not on, only mobile data and location services. I drove through and area and it just kept showing me on the map with a large circle around me. When I pulled the times it has me in one location and the next minute jumping to a location that is 10 miles away.

How can that happen? Did I lock onto a cell tower? The previous 3 days passed the same place but never picked me up. Times of travel were different on the previous 3 days.

Comment: It sounds like you already understand that with GPS turned off the location won't be accurate, so I'm not sure what you're asking. What's left to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings > location > mode and select high accuracy. This will ensure that the gps is used for location.

Comment: Without the GPS on how accurate can it be then? I see other times it looks like I'm walking around me neighborhood. I'm sure that has to do with wifi.

Comment: Without gps it will use the mobile towers to find your location

Comment: And wifi, as @jennifer mentioned.